# Icache performance for the following code fragment

Tags: performance, caching, optimization

I have a block of code that goes

```
for ( ... ) 
{
    if (condition) {
       // some code
    }
    // some more code
}
```

Code within the `if` condition and outside are of decent size. The condition is either always true or always false, so there shouldn't be any branch prediction misses. In the case where the condition is always `false`, will the code within the `if` condition be removed from the instruction cache? Is there some way I can optimize this for the icache?

Comment: it is always true or false at comile time? from start of runtime?

Comment: IMO This would need to be a question about a single type of processor - different processors would behave differently, so there's no universal answer.

Comment: Its aimed at x86-64 processors.

Answer (score 0):

In general I have found it to be better to do something more like this:

```
if (condition) {
     for ( ... ) 
      {
      // some code
      }
}
else
{
     for (...)
     {
     // some more code
     }
}
```

If the `if clause` is indeed an invarient

If this occurs multiple times - you can select a function pointer or functor that contains the for loop and just call that after the decision is made:

```
func = (condition) ? func1 : func2
```

and then call `func` everywhere

Comment: The function pointer will act as an unpredictable branch afaik.

Comment: @usr it is set at the beginning of the program, once state is established, from then on it is just called - there is no branch at all

Comment: But the CPU cannot predict where execution will go. There are infinitely many possible targets. Not sure about this, though.

Comment: @usr its basically the same as a roll your own virtual function.   Are stating that there is no prefetch, or are you stating that it is a branch miss?

Comment: I'm saying that any type of indirect call stalls the pipeline until the target has been computed. It is my understanding that this stall is the major cost component of indirect jumps/calls. A correctly predicted branch has almost no latency.

Comment: @usr since it wraps the for loop - it may or may not be a factor, too many other variables come to play, as it now has to weighed against the cost of repeating the code.